# Problems with the KINO-PV-D5253-R10

Tags: windows-7

We have a problem with the ***KINO-PV-D5253-R10***. We have to assign 4 GB of RAM but when we do that the PC will not boot, When we have 2GB of RAM it works perfectly. Are there any known problems wich can help me because i could not find anything. The system works on windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this question correctly, you are saying the board will not boot with 4 GB of RAM but will boot fine with 2 GB. The specifications pages I can find related to this seem a bit unclear as to the size of each RAM stick. I see 2 slots but the board page lists only 4 GB and doesn't break it down to 2 sticks of 2 GB each. If you are trying to use a single stick of 4 GB, Your board will not boot as it doesn't support RAM in thaqt configuration.

If I am misunderstanding what you have asked and you are using 2 sticks pf 2 GB RAM and your board doesn't boot, you may have a bad RAM stick or a bad RAM slot. The easiest way to find out would be to boot the board using the other RAM slot and switch the RAM sticks after a successful boot and shutdown.

Comment: We have tried to switch the 2 RAM sticks but it doesnt work, The system installed is windows 7 64 bit. Do you know any other solution?

Comment: A quick read through of the manual doesn't help any. There is no hint as to what this might be. I would suggest a bad RAM stick again and/or a bad RAM slot. There doesn't seem to be a 3rd option.

Comment: We have figgured out the problem. We had two of the same KINO's but the first one had an older bios version and the second one had an newer bios version. The first brios version was not compatible with 4 GB of ram\